# Computing henselization DVR

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, local-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a DVR with fraction field $K$ and call $\hat{R}$ its completion. I would like to show that the henselization of $R$ consists of the element of $\hat{R}$ which are separable over $K$, trying to follow the path of this answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105381/henselization-and-completion.

I've got one problem with the proof that is showing that $B_F$ is etale over $R$ and in particular I do not get why $B_F$ should be finitely generated over $R$ .

My problem would be solved if the following thing is true:$\hat{R} \cap K^{sep}$ is exactly the set of elements $x \in \hat{R}$ that are integral and separable over $R$. In this case, $B_F$ would be the integral closure of $R$ in a finite separable extension and so it would be finite over $R$ (this shuld be a general fact about normal noetherian rings).I've tried to prove this claim, but I'm not getting anything.

Comment: In the answer it is used that the map $R \to B_L$ is etale which by definition also includes that $B_L$n is a finitely generated $R$ algebra. maybe there is an alternative way to prove the result but I do not have any other ideas

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio In the answer is not used that $R\to B_L$ is étale, just uses what he call the property (a), and you don't need étale. Also, it is not true in general that the $B$ is finitely generated $R$-algebra. What he uses is that $B_F$ is étale, where $F/K$ is **finite** separable extension. And in this case finite generation is true (and very easy).

Comment: Sorry  I meant finite separabile extension. I still do noto know how to prove

Comment: Allo what is your definition of henselization of a DVR (of course I meant $\overline{Frac(R)} \cap \hat{R}$ or $\overline{Frac(R)} \cap \hat{R}^{unr}$ where $\hat{R}$ is the completion for $|a| = 2^{-v(a)}$ and $\hat{R}^{unr}$ is obtained by adding to $\hat{R}$ the roots of monic polynomials that are separable $\bmod (\pi)$). If it is the smallest DVR extending $R$ where Hensel lemma holds I think it is immediate it is .$\overline{Frac(R)} \cap \hat{R}$

Comment: I'm still not getting why the map should be etale @xarles. While reuns I did not understand your last comment sorry

Comment: I meant the map $R \to B_F$ with $F$ finite separable extension @xarles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*My problem would be solved if the following thing is true:$\hat{R} \cap K^{sep}$ is exactly the set of elements $x \in \hat{R}$ that are integral and separable over $R$.*

---

This is in general not true. Take for example $R = \mathbb{Z}_3 \cap \mathbb{Q} = \{\frac{a}{b}: a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, \gcd(a, b) = 1, 3\nmid b\}$. Then we have $K^{sep} = \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $\hat{R} = \mathbb{Z}_3$.

Now there is an element $\alpha \in \hat{R}$ such that $3\alpha^2-2\alpha-2 = 0$ (the existence of $\alpha$ follows from Hensel's lemma). Thus $\alpha$ lies in the intersection $\hat{R} \cap K^{sep}$.

However, it is also clear that $\alpha$ is not integral over $R$.

Comment: How do you apply Hensel lemma if the polynomium is not monic?

Comment: Hensel's lemma doesn't require the polynomial to be monic. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma for details.